# How do I conditionally/dynamically include Razor subpages in an Asp.Net Core Razor page?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

New to Asp.Net Core/Razor here.

I am building a Asp.Net Core Razor page.
I have a main Razor page which serves as a parent page.
I have a collection of sub pages (over 20 different children types).

I would like to be able to conditionally include a child page
based on an identifier in my parent page's view model.

**The basic simplified version of my parent Razor page would look something like this:**

```
@model DocumentsViewModel

<div>
<!-- Some basic common form functionality--!>
</div>

<div class="WhereToEmbedChildForm">
        @Html.Partial("SomeChildViewName")

        @{ Html.RenderPartial("SomeChildViewName"); }

        @{<partial name="SomeChildViewName" for="CurrentDocumentTypeViewModel"/>}
</div>
```

**My parent page view model would look something like this:**

```
public class SampleModel
{
   public int ChildViewType { get; set; }
   public string ChildViewModelName { get; set; } 
}
```

**To accomplish this, I have some questions:**

1. Is it possible to dynamically create my ViewModel object (DynamicObject) to include the
   child's view model?
2. How would I dynamically include the child view (and associated view model) in my parent page?
3. Should I be using  or @Html.Partial()/@{Html.RenderPartial} ?
4. Given Razor, is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Hi John. Tried to get in touch with you on the chat earlier. What I wrote there, is that instead of annotating a lot classes, you should consider registering the binder like I show in the answer I sent you. You may also want to have a look at using IFormCollection in your controller method as an alternative. BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that using tag library is preferred above HTML helpers when creating new apps.

A proof-of-concept:

Updated version of `SampleModel`:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public object ChildViewModel { get; set; } 
    public string ChildViewName { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple child model

```
public class ModelForPartialOne
{
    public string SomeDemoProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In controller

```
private ModelForPartialOne GetModelForPartialOneWithDataFromDb()
{
    // just a mock db call
    return new ModelForPartialOne {SomeDemoProperty = "Hello from one"};
}

public IActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
    const int childViewType = 42; // you will get this from somewhere
    
    switch (childViewType)
    {
        case 42:
            return View(new SampleModel
            {
                ChildViewModel = GetModelForPartialOneWithDataFromDb(),
                ChildViewName = "_partialOne",
            });
    }
}
```

In main Razor view

```
@model SampleModel

<div class="WhereToEmbedChildForm">
    <partial name="@Model.ChildViewName" model="@Model.ChildViewModel"/>
</div>
```

_partialOne.cshtml

```
@model ModelForPartialOne

<h1>Hello from partial one</h1>
<p>SomeDemoProperty: @Model.SomeDemoProperty</p>
```

In order to avoid a bloated controller, logic for populating view models should be delegated to business logic services.

Alternative to the above solution, is to use view components.

Code is tested using a Core 5 MVC app.

**Update**

OP asked me this later on:

> However, now I'm attempting to retrieve data from my partial view on a
> PostBack. The submit button lives on my parent page.

Let's rewrite the main view like this:

```
@model SampleModel

<div class="WhereToEmbedChildForm">
    <form method="post" asp-action="@Model.PostbackAction">
        <partial name="@Model.ChildViewName" model="@Model.ChildViewModel"/>
        <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

We'll need a partial *_partialTwo.cshtml* with form data like this:

```
@model ModelForPartialOne

Some demo property:
<input asp-for="SomeDemoProperty">
```

Add this property to `SampleModel`: `public string PostbackAction { get; set; }`

And modify controller GET method to return this:

```
return View(new SampleModel
{
    ChildViewModel = GetModelForPartialOneWithDataFromDb(),
    ChildViewName = "_partialTwo",
    PostbackAction = "MyPostbackAction"
});
```

With the above changes, we're able to open a page with a form. Now we'll need a controller action to handle the postback. This is where the fun stops, because we cannot use object as type for model parameter in POST method; the code needs to know the type to use for model binding.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyPostbackAction(ModelForPartialOne model)
{
    // do something
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: This is right in line for what I'm trying to do. I have a couple of questions (new to Razor here and dynamic substitution).  [1] - Is it possible to do dynamically set <partial name="@model.DynamicPartialName"/>? I have upwards of 20-30 different possible subpages?  [2] - How do I load child page data (retrieved from DB), does each child page need it's own controller, or would I load that from the main page's controller?

Comment: @JohnB: Question #1: Yes, I've updated my answer with this. Question #2: Please see my updated answer. BR

Comment: Worked like a charm exactly as advertised. This cleans up my implementation considerably. Thx so much!

Comment: @Roar.S - Everything you described works as advertised. However, now I'm attempting to retrieve data from my partial view on a PostBack.  The submit button lives on my parent page. LMK if I should enter a new question for this. Thx

Comment: @JohnB: I've added a solution for postback at the bottom of my answer. I hope I understood your requirements for this. BR

Comment: @Roar.S - This is close, but not quite for what I'm trying to do. I apologize for not being clear in my description. Consider my model looks like this: 
public class SampleModel
{
    public object ChildViewModel { get; set; } 
    public string ChildViewName { get; set; }
 public Document CurDocument { get; set; }
 public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}.

Currently in my PostBack, ChildViewModel is null. I need access to all fields in the SampleModel object in the post back (both parent and child. Thx.

Comment: @JohnB: As I wrote in my last update, the framework is not very happy when posting models of tyoe object, because the model binder does not know which class to create. This can be solved somehow using custom binders, but that is not very in line with your dynamic solution.

Comment: @Roar.S - Is it possible to do something like client-side serialize the child-data to a string in the parent Model? I could then inflate the object to class as needed on the server? It breaks the pattern to try to retrieve hidden field value from controller (if that's even possible). Thoughts?

Comment: @JohnB: That may be a solution, but it has to be done on the client side before posting the data. I'm not that experienced with these kind of special solutions, but I know there are guys in here that loves this kind of challenges :-)

Comment: @Roar.S - I've been trying to get something work here. The challenge I have is accessing ModelData from within a javascript function on the page.  I guess I should post a new thread for that...?

Comment: @JohnB: I believe posting a new question for that part will give you both a faster and a better answer than I can give you on that field. BR

Comment: @Roar.S - You mentioned custom binders in one of your previous comments. Can you point me in the direction of an example that would be useful to my approach? I don't think my serialization in javascript approach will work.

Comment: @JohnB: I wrote this binder a couple of weeks ago. This is a simple binder, but you should be able to debug this and find the data you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68237163/14072498 And this is the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Roar.S - Once again many thanks to the attention you are giving my question(s).  Consider my example where I have N different child models which are abstracted to an object within the parent model. I would decorate those child model definitions with something similar to this: [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(AuthorEntityBinder))]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235160/discussion-between-roar-s-and-johnb).